# how to inherit Part of Constructor from super class to sub class in java

Tags: java, inheritance, subclass, superclass, extends

How to inherit some parameters of superclass constructor to subclass constructor?
For example I want only weight and height to be inherited to subclass, how to construct the constractor for subclass?

```
public abstract class People {

    protected double weight;

    protected int height;

    protected String mood;

    public People(double weight, int height, String mood) {

        this.weight = weight;
        this.mood = mood;
}

public class Health extends People {

    private String bloodType;

    public Health(double weight, int height, String bloodType){
        super(weight,height); // this won't work
        this.bloodType = bloodType;
}
```

Comment: `public Question` for a class called `People`? Does that even compile?

Comment: Although not recomended you can do this `super(weight,height,"");` in you `Health` Class constructor, just to provide a empty String value for the parameter. Or else the better way provide one more constructor in super/concrete class with params `(double weight, int height)`

Answer (score 1):

*Either* you need to supply a mood to the constructor in the superclass (possibly as a constant), *or* you need to add a constructor to the superclass which doesn't take a mood. You need to ask yourself whether every `Question/People` really *needs* a mood, and what the mood of a `DivisionQuestion/Health` is. (It doesn't help that your code is currently inconsistent in terms of the classnames it's using.)

Just like calling a normal method, you can't provide arguments for *some* parameters but not others.

Answer (score 0):

you just need to overload the constructor  or can have default values for variable "mood" in the Super Class. nevertheless [Effective Java](http://www.amazon.in/Effective-Java-Joshua-Bloch/dp/8131726592?tag=googinhydr2731-21) advices to use static factory methods instead of overloading the constructor.

Answer (score 0):

Just to complement Jon Skeets and Harshil Sukhadias answers. You either need two constructors, one accepting only `height` and `weight` and sets a default for `mood` or you call your first constructor with a default.

```
public abstract class People {
    // ...
    public static final String MOOD_DEFAULT = "Happy";
    public People(double weight, int height, String mood) {
        // ...
    }
    // second ctor, calling the first with a default for mood...
    public People(double weight, int height) {
       this(weight,height,Question.MOOD_DEFAULT);
    }
}

public class Health extends People{
    // ...
    public Health(double weight, int height, String bloodType) {
        super(weight,height);
        // ... or super(weight,height,Question.MOOD_DEFAULT);
    }
}
```

Having this type of class hierarchy it might be useful to implement the builder pattern, have a look at chapter 2, item 2 of Josuah Blochs "Effective Java" for more details.